# Perl: Net::SNMP not delivering email to gmail but normal 'mail -s' is

Tags: perl, email, smtp, gmail

I wrote a Perl script (on machine A) that sends a mail out to another server (machine B), which bounces it back (either using procmail or other forwarding mechanisms, depending on machine B), and then the script on machine A measures the round trip time.

This was working fine for a long while now, but for some reason this has stopped working when machine B is GMAIL.

Here's how I debugged it:

1. I tried sending a similar message using 'mail -s' from the command line, and that mail delivered without any problems - so the mail relay isn't the issue.

   ```
   mailbounce@machineA.com:~$mail -s 'Round Trip Test 1366102726' mailbouncexxxxx@gmail.com
   A simple test message From The Mail Round Trip Monitor...
   .
   cc:
   mailbounce@machineA.com:~$
   ```
2. Next, I changed the 'to:' address to another machine, which I own, just to see whether the script works. It worked without issues to another server (not gmail)
3. Next, I reverted the script back to original parameters. I started a tcpdump on port 25 and ran the script, and thereafter sent the mail using the command line as well. When analyzing the packet capture in Wireshark and doing a 'Follow TCP Stream', the output is as follows:

**Using the script(Did not deliver):**

```
    220 mail.out.com ESMTP Exim 4.74 Tue, 16 Apr 2013 10:58:36 +0200
    EHLO machineA.domain.com
    250-mail.out.com Hello machineA.domain.com [10.184.55.248]
    250-SIZE 13631488
    250-PIPELINING
    250 HELP
    MAIL FROM:<mailbounce@ machineA.domain.com>
    250 OK
    RCPT TO:<mailbouncexxxxx@gmail.com>
    250 Accepted
    DATA
    354 Enter message, ending with "." on a line by itself
    To: mailbouncexxxxx@gmail.com
    Subject: Round Trip Test 1366102726

    A simple test message From The Mail Round Trip Monitor...
    .
    250 OK id=1US1im-000Lr0-Qd
    QUIT
    221 mail.out.com closing connection
```

**Using the command line (delivered successfully):**

```
    220 mail.out.com ESMTP Exim 4.74 Tue, 16 Apr 2013 10:59:02 +0200
    EHLO machineA.domain.com
    250-mail.out.com Hello machineA.domain.com [10.184.55.248]
    250-SIZE 13631488
    250-PIPELINING
    250 HELP
    MAIL From:<mailbounce@machineA.domain.com> SIZE=635
    250 OK
    RCPT To:<mailbouncexxxxx@gmail.com>
    DATA
    250 Accepted
    354 Enter message, ending with "." on a line by itself
    Received: from machineA.domain.com (localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1])
    .by machineA.domain.com (8.13.8/8.13.8) with ESMTP id r3G8x0jq015631
    .for <mailbouncexxxxx@gmail.com>; Tue, 16 Apr 2013 10:59:00 +0200
    Received: (from mailbounce@localhost)
    .by machineA.domain.com (8.13.8/8.13.8/Submit) id r3G8wxGJ015622
    .for mailbouncexxxxx@gmail.com; Tue, 16 Apr 2013 10:58:59 +0200
    Date: Tue, 16 Apr 2013 10:58:59 +0200
    From: mailbounce User <mailbounce@machineA.domain.com>
    Message-Id: <201304160858.r3G8wxGJ015622@machineA.domain.com>
    To: mailbouncexxxxx@gmail.com
    Subject: test2

    test
    .
    250 OK id=1US1jC-000LvF-OQ
    QUIT
    221 mail.out.com closing connection
```

According to what I'm seeing above, this should be working withou a hitch? I've checked the 'SPAM' folder in the gmail account as well, but no luck

Why would my mails not deliver when using Net::SMTP as opposed to using the command line...via the same SMTP relay? I've run out of places to look.

Notes:

1. Before creating this question, I looked at [How can I debug my Net::SMTP Perl program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657478/how-can-i-debug-my-netsmtp-perl-program) . I didn't find any other relevant information on the internet.
2. The hostnames, email accounts and IP addresses above are ficticious - that's all that is modified from the input/outputs

Comment: In both cases, the server at mail.out.com accepted the mails for delivery and gave you the queue IDs. Your next step must be to look at the maillogs on that server and look for information about those queue id's.

Comment: From your script output it seems your test message is missing important headers (Date, From, Message-ID), your'e only sending 'To' and 'Subject'.

Comment: Nope, it's all there. The 'date' is in the first line for instance. The from is automatically set to '[user]@[fqdn]' for instance if you use the command line utility 'mail'. The 'message-id' is in the 3rd line from the bottom.

My problem lies in the fact that I don't control the mail.out.com server, so I don't have direct access to the mail logs on that machine. Will have to talk to the admin (if I can figure out who it is)

Thanks for the comments though